# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED }

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I'am writing this code to learn how use Bluetooth in Android however i'am constantly getting the error mentioned in the title. Full error is: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED }`

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <application 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <receiver
            android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
        <activity 
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private final String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static int REQUEST_STATE_CHANGED_BT = 2;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        BluetoothAdapter oBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
        if (oBTAdapter == null) Log.i(LOG_TAG, "This device does not support Bluetooth");
        if (!oBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent iEnableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(iEnableBT, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);           
        }
        Intent iBTStatus = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        startActivityForResult(iBTStatus, REQUEST_STATE_CHANGED_BT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Bluetooth was not enabled on the device");
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_STATE_CHANGED_BT) 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && !data.getStringExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE).equals(BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON)) Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Bluetooth adapter is not on");   
    }    
}
```

On the device i have bluetooth on and with the logs i saw that it did skip the isEnabled() test(to see of Bluetooth is currently enabled and ready for use). It was able to create an intent to observe Bluetooth status but it crashes on startActivityForResult(). What did i do wrong?

Comment: what exactly you trying to achieve why same names for receiver and activity as `MainActivity`

Comment: Isn't name of receiver the class that will receive the intents?

Comment: add the details about what exactly you want to do with both receiver and activity

Comment: I didn't notice that on the documentation it says "ACTION_STATE_CHANGED" and below "Broadcast Action: The state of the local Bluetooth adapter has been changed. " So whenever we have action that has this Brodcast Action we need to use instantiate a BroadcastReceiver in order to receive intents, right? I was handling that as normal intent and using onActivityResult() to see response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you have not any activity with that kind of event handling, 
you should try to make BroadcastReceiver like this

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
        final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                                             BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
        switch (state) {
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
            setButtonText("Bluetooth off");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
            setButtonText("Turning Bluetooth off...");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
            setButtonText("Bluetooth on");
            break;
        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
            setButtonText("Turning Bluetooth on...");
            break;
        }
    }
}
};
```

And in your activity do it like this...

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: I need a BrodcastReceiver because i used <receiver> in AndroidManifest.xml? Previously i had just an intent filter inside MainActivity like this `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>` but it didn't work so i then tried receiver. I will try your solution. I'd like to know still why doesn't adding intent filter inside MainActivity work. I sent an intent and declared MainActivity to be able to handle that intent. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: what you need is receiver not an activity. try if my solution work for you.

Comment: It did work. I did it just a bit different. I declared a class that extends BroadcastReceiver and added the code there. Then in AndroidManifest file i added <receiver> with name of class that extends BroadcastReceiver. I didn't need last part of IntentFilter in Java code. If someone thinks this is not good practice let me know but all works now.